# 28-Band Graphic Equalizer in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filters, audio, filter-design, dft

I'm trying to design a MATLAB audio player that includes something like a 31-band equalizer. Right now I have the filters working by using the `FIR1()` function to create an FIR bandpass filter at each frequency specified on the bands. This is great except that it's not exactly what I'm wanting to do. I want to either boost or cut the desired frequency, not isolate the frequency.

How would I go about using these FIR filters in parallel to boost or cut the signal instead of just isolating the signal?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the peakingEQ biquad filter by [Robert Bristow-Johnson](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt), you can use it to increase or attenuate one frequency or band-frequency, this can be easy to implement in matlab, I used to test and compare some filters, and it seems to work very well to equalizer, you can choose one dB input to do the work !

Answer (score 0):

Best choice for a graphical EQ are the aforementioned biquad filters in cascade NOT in parallel.

Parallel bandpass filter create lots of interference at the band edges and a very non uniform group delay even in the "flat" setting. There is no way to implement a flat transfer function with parallel band passes. The cascaded are perfectly flat in both amplitude and phase when the gain of every stage is 0 dB. It's also computationally a lot more efficient.

Comment: I will have to disagree. The parallel bandpass does not need to have interference (amplitude and phase) for the neutral setting. One of the parallel branches can be a gain. See the reference I mentioned here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9341/naudio-real-time-equalizer?rq=1